# Choose row when grouping sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id | field_1 | field_2
1  | a       | 1
2  | b       | 1

SELECT id, field_1 FROM table GROUP BY field_2
```

This will get the row where id = 1, how can I get the row with the greatest id? (I want to get field_1 = b). Which is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See Also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.field_1, t2.IdSum
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT field_2, MAX(id) id, SUM(id) IdSum
  FROM  Table
  GROUP BY field_2
) t2  on t1.id = t2.id
     AND t1.field_2 = t2.field_2;
```

Comment: Thank you! I also want to return how many rows the group included, I tried adding SUM(1) to the first SELECT, but that made the grouping fail. Would you know how to do?

Answer (score 2):

This expression does *not* get the the first row by definition:

```
SELECT id, field_1
FROM table
GROUP BY field_2
```

What it does it get values from *arbitrary* rows for each value of `field2`.  The arbitrary row may be the first row, but there is no guarantee.  Look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html) for Hidden Columns to understand this.

In MySQL you need a join to get the row with the highest id.  Here is one way:

```
select t.*
from t
where id = (select max(id) from t t2 where t2.field2 = t.field2)
```

This will fetch all rows with the highest id for each value of field2.